# How to add depedency overriding in FastAPI testing

Tags: python, testing, fastapi

I'm new to FastAPI, I have implemented everything but when it comes to testing the API I can't override a dependency.

Here is my code:

***test_controller.py***

```
import pytest
from starlette.testclient import TestClient
from app.main import app
from app.core.manager_imp import ManagerImp


@pytest.fixture()
def client():
    with TestClient(app) as test_client:
        yield test_client


async def over_create_record():
    return {"msg": "inserted successfully"}

app.dependency_overrides[ManagerImp.create_record] = over_create_record

def test_post(client):
    data = {"name": "John", "email": "john@abc.com"}
    response = client.post("/person/", json=data)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {"msg": "inserted successfully"}
```

***controller.py***

```
from app.controllers.v1.controller import Controller
from fastapi import status, HTTPException
from app.models.taxslip import Person
from app.core.manager_imp import ManagerImp
from app.core.duplicate_exception import DuplicateException
from fastapi_utils.cbv import cbv
from fastapi_utils.inferring_router import InferringRouter

router = InferringRouter(tags=["Person"]) 
@cbv(router)
class ControllerImp(Controller):
    manager = ManagerImp()

    @router.post("/person/")
    async def create_record(self, person: Person):
        """
        Person: A person object
        returns response if the person was inserted into the database
        """
        try:
            response = await self.manager.create_record(person.dict())
            return response
        except DuplicateException as e:
            return e
```

***manager_imp.py***

```
from fastapi import HTTPException, status
from app.database.database_imp import DatabaseImp
from app.core.manager import Manager
from app.core.duplicate_exception import DuplicateException


class ManagerImp(Manager):
    database = DatabaseImp()
    async def create_record(self, taxslip: dict):
        try:
            response = await self.database.add(taxslip)
            return response
        except DuplicateException:
            raise HTTPException(409, "Duplicate data")
```

In testing I want to override create_record function from ManagerImp class so that I could get this response `{"msg": "inserted successfully"}`. Basically, I want to mock ManagerImp create_record function. I have tried as you can see in `test_controller.py` but I still get the original response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the dependency injection system to get the `ManagerImp.create_record` function, so there is nothing to override.

Since you're not using FastAPI's `Depends` to get your dependency - FastAPI has no way of returning the alternative function.

In your case you'll need to use a regular mocking library instead, such as unittest.mock or [pytest-mock](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/).

I'd also like to point out that initializing a shared dependency as in you've done here *by default* will share the same instance across all instances of `ControllerImp` instead of being re-created for each instance of `ControllerImp`.

[The cbv decorator changes things a bit](https://fastapi-utils.davidmontague.xyz/user-guide/class-based-views/#the-cbv-decorator), and as mentioned in the documentation:

> For each shared dependency, add a class attribute with a value of type `Depends`

So to get this to match the FastAPI way of doing things and make the `cbv` decorator work as you want to:

```
def get_manager():
    return ManagerImp()

@cbv(router)
class ControllerImp(Controller):
    manager = Depends(get_manager)
```

And when you do it this way, you can use `dependency_overrides` as you planned:

```
app.dependency_overrides[get_manager] = lambda: return MyFakeManager()
```

If you only want to replace the `create_record` function, you'll still have to use regular mocking.

You'll also have to remove the dependency override after the test has finished unless you want it to apply to all tests, so use `yield` inside your fixture and then remove the override when the fixture starts executing again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put your `app.dependency_overrides` inside the function with `@pytest.fixture`. Try to put it inside your `client()`.

```
@pytest.fixture()
def client():
    app.dependency_overrides[ManagerImp.create_record] = over_create_record
    with TestClient(app) as test_client:
        yield test_client
```

because every test will run the fresh `app`, meaning it will reset everything from one to another test and only related things bind with the `pytest` will effect the test.

Comment: I already tried this but it doesn't work.

Comment: I think you should put your fixture and config in different file named `conftest.py` in the same folder with your `test_controller.py`